# When was PCI first introduced?

Tags: pci

Now I have noticed on different sites that there exists conflicting information.  Intel, which I obviously trust the most as well as Wikipedia says 1992.

Strangely, a fairly reputable source, that is teaching for those A+ exams is teaching students that it was introduced in 1994.

Yet another website says that it was introduced in 1993.

1992:
http://www.intel.ie/content/dam/doc/case-study/intel-pci-pci-express-3-case-study.pdf

1994:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERc1r7oE-XA (5:04--note:  if you are learning about bus architecture, aside from this discrepancy..actually proves to be a real good learning basis)

1993:
turbofuture.com/computers/buses

Pretty much, I'm just looking for this question to be answered by those who are really in the know, or who were around during that era and could perhaps shed some light onto the situation.

Either way, I think that this is an issue that should be addressed as people are teaching students the wrong thing!

I don't know if this is a microcosm of the 'do your research' thing, is irrelevant as a whole, or really does matter.  All I know is that to me it does, and I am curious.

Cheers.

Comment: I would point out that knowing that is not particularly helpful to a developing IT professional.  This is not history class. Names and Dates are not terribly helpful to decision making in the field.

Comment: Thanks for driving that home, I was more looking to open dialogue with seasoned vets, and it seems to have served its purpose in more than one regard.  Cheers

Answer (score 3):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI#History:

> PCI was immediately put to use in servers, replacing MCA and EISA as
>   the server expansion bus of choice. In mainstream PCs, PCI was slower
>   to replace VESA Local Bus (VLB), and **did not gain significant market
>   penetration until late 1994** in second-generation Pentium PCs.

I would hazard a guess that this is where the discrepancy comes from: Original introduction vs. widespread adoption.

Edit: Also:

```
 Spec           Year          Change summary
 PCI 1.0        1992          Original issue
 PCI 2.0        1993          Incorporated connector and add-in card specification
```

So I guess there is some debate as to when it caught on.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't read far enough into that article.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The first (non-draft) Intel spec for the PCI 1.0 standard was released in 1992.

First servers on the market (IBM and Dec if I remember correctly) where in 1993.
I attended CeBIT in Hannover that year and IBM had a huge stand demoing them. I clearly remember that CeBIT because it was my first visit to a major trade-show and it left an impression.

It wasn't until 1994 that they started to show up in regular PC's. I bought a 486 that year and I couldn't find one (that i could afford that is) with PCI and had to settle for Vesa Local Bus.
The other reason that 1994 is often quoted is that the oldest PCI spec downloadable from the PCI-SIG web-site dates from 1994 (but that is already a PIC 2.0 spec.)

Comment: The insight and experience is greatly appreciated.  Thank you for sharing